# How do you Programmatically set DataGridViewComboBoxCell value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble setting the value of DataGridViewComboBoxCell.  The datagridview column is bound with choices/values but when I attempt either dgv.Rows.Add with specified column values for the comboBoxCells OR setting the cell's value seperately, it generates the "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid" error.  If I add a row with blank values for those column, the choices display in the combo just fine.

I have a dialog that is passed an arraylist of a simple object, NDCRecord.

```
public class NDCRecord
    {        
        public string NDCcode = "";
        public string UnitQuantity = "";
        public string UnitOfMeasurement = "";
        public string Type = "";
        public string Number = ""; 
    }
```

In the dialog a datagrid is created programmatically and then is repopulated.

```
public NationalDrugCodesForm(ref ArrayList ndcRecordsIn)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ndcRecords = ndcRecordsIn;            
            SetupDataGridViewColumns();
            PopulateForm();
        }
```

Setup:

```
private void SetupDataGridViewColumns()
        {

            // -----------------------------------------------------
            // Add/Del column
            // -----------------------------------------------------
            DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbcAddRemove = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            dgvbcAddRemove.HeaderText = "Add";
            dgvbcAddRemove.Text = "Add";
            dgvbcAddRemove.Name = "Add";

            DataGridViewCellStyle addButtonStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            addButtonStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            addButtonStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            dgvbcAddRemove.HeaderCell.Style = addButtonStyle;

            dgvNDC.Columns.Add(dgvbcAddRemove);

            // -----------------------------------------------------
            // Additional Columns
            // -----------------------------------------------------
            dgvNDC.Columns.Add("NDCCode", "NDC Code");

            dgvNDC.Columns.Add("UnitQuantity", "Unit Quantity");

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn unitOfMeasurement = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            unitOfMeasurement.HeaderText = "Unit Of Measurement";
            unitOfMeasurement.Name = "UnitOfMeasurement";
            dgvNDC.Columns.Add(unitOfMeasurement);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn type = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            type.HeaderText = "Type";
            type.Name = "Type";
            dgvNDC.Columns.Add(type);

            dgvNDC.Columns.Add("Number", "Prescription Number");

            AddLine("Del", "", "", "", "", "");

            BindUnitOfMeasurement((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvNDC.Rows[0].Cells["UnitOfMeasurement"]);
            BindType((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvNDC.Rows[0].Cells["Type"]);            
        }
```

The AddLine function:

```
    private void AddLine(string buttonLabel, string ndcCode, string unitQuantity, string unitOfMeasurement, string type, string rxNumber)
    {
        dgvNDC.Rows.Add(new object[] { buttonLabel, ndcCode, unitQuantity, unitOfMeasurement, type, rxNumber });
    }
```

The binding functions:

```
    private void BindUnitOfMeasurement(DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb)
    {
        string[] Values = { "F2", "GR", "ME", "ML", "UN" };
        string[] Choices = { "F2 - International Unit", "GR - Gram", "ME - Milligram", "ML - Milliliter", "UN - Unit" };

        ControlManip.DataBindDDL(cb, Choices, Values);
    }

    private void BindType(DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb)
    {
        string[] Values = { "XZ", "VY" };
        string[] Choices = { "XZ - Prescription Number", "VY - Link Sequence Number" };

        ControlManip.DataBindDDL(cb, Choices, Values);
        cb.Value = "XZ";
    }
public static void DataBindDDL(ref ComboBox cb, string[] Choices, string[] Values)
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      dt.Columns.Add("Choice");
      dt.Columns.Add("Value");

      if (Choices.Length != Values.Length)
      {
        throw new Exception("Number of Choices and Values do not match!");
      }
      else
      {
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "" });
        for (int i = 0; i < Choices.Length; i++)
        {
          if (Choices[i] is object && Values[i] is object)
          {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { Choices[i], Values[i] });
          }
        }

        cb.DataSource = dt;
        cb.DisplayMember = "Choice";
        cb.ValueMember = "Value";
      }
    }
```

Populate the form:

```
    private void PopulateForm()
    {
        if (ndcRecords == null || ndcRecords.Count == 0)
            return;

        dgvNDC.Rows.Clear();

        foreach(NDCRecord record in ndcRecords)
        {
            AddLine("Del", record.NDCcode, record.UnitQuantity, record.UnitOfMeasurement, record.Type, record.Number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To simplify...  I set up a datagrid with combo box columns and bind those columns to a datasource.  When adding rows with blank values for those columns, everything looks fine; the combos have the choices they should.  If I try to add a row with the values specified, and they are valid choices that exist for the values of the combo boxes, I get the error.  I noticed in debugging that the cell has no "items" which seems to be a problem...  but don't understand because the choices are there when the value is not set.

Comment: Note that the ValueMember and DisplayMember were being set on the CELL in the binding method.  I set ValueMember, DisplayMember, and DataPropertyName on the COLUMN...  but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was binding individual CELLs instead of the COLUMNS that contained the drop-down box.  I had inserted bind methods where the "Add" button was clicked that made it appear as though adding a row with blank values still resulted in populated dropdowns.  But adding a row with values specified caused an error because the row's dropdown columns had nothing in their collection yet.  So here are the important modifications to the code:

In SetupDataGridViewColumns instead of

```
    BindUnitOfMeasurement((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvNDC.Rows[0].Cells["UnitOfMeasurement"]);
BindType((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvNDC.Rows[0].Cells["Type"]);
```

use

```
BindUnitOfMeasurement((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvNDC.Columns["UnitOfMeasurement"]);
BindType((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvNDC.Columns["Type"]);
```

and modify the binding methods appropriately.  Then, you can add a row with blank values for the combo, or specified values, and it will work (below one of them has a value specified for default, the other is left blank for the user to select from)

```
AddLine("Del", "", "", "", "XZ", "");
```

Also, I'm not sure if this was necessary but in the course of experimenting I also added this for each combobox column:

```
type.ValueType = typeof (string);
```